# This code searches for an object which meets mathematical Max, Min, or less than/greater than criteria at certain counter i points

Tags: javascript, beginner

I am new to JavaScript.  The below code works on array y from tree values of 1 to 5, but I want to extend it to check trees value of 100.

array y is of the type [{key:value, key:value}, {key:value, key:value}]

I was wondering if I can I implement a loop within the repeating portion of the body of the code?

Thanks in advance for anyone who may know how to do this.

Thank you

```
z = y.length

for (let i = 0; i < z; i++)
y[i].coupons = 0;


for (let i = 49; i < (z - 1); i++) {
cval = y[i].trees

if (y[i].trees > 0 && y[i].coconuts > 0 && (i + cval) < (z-1)) {

    if (y[i].trees === 1 ) {

        if (y[i].lentils > y[i].coconuts 
            && y[i + 1].apples > y[i].coconuts && y[i + 1].onions < y[i].coconuts && y[i+1].horses < y[i+1].maple) {
        y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts
        }
    } else if (y[i].trees === 2) {

        if (y[i].lentils > y[i].coconuts                                                                                                  
            && y[i + 1].apples > y[i].coconuts && y[i + 1].onions < y[i].coconuts && y[i + 1].horses < y[i + 1].maple
            && y[i + 2].horses < y[i].coconuts) {
            y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts                                                                                                     
        } else if (Math.min(y[i].lentils, y[i + 1].lentils) > y[i].coconuts                                                               
            && y[i + 2].apples > y[i].coconuts && y[i + 2].onions < y[i].coconuts && y[i + 2].horses < y[i + 2].maple) {
            y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts
        }
    } else if (y[i].trees === 3) {

        if (y[i].lentils > y[i].coconuts                                                                                                 
            && y[i + 1].apples > y[i].coconuts && y[i + 1].onions < y[i].coconuts && y[i + 1].horses < y[i + 1].maple
            && Math.max(y[i + 2].horses, y[i + 3].horses) < y[i].coconuts) {
            y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts
        } else if (Math.min(y[i].lentils, y[i + 1].lentils) > y[i].coconuts
            && y[i + 2].apples > y[i].coconuts && y[i + 2].onions < y[i].coconuts && y[i + 2].horses < y[i + 2].maple
            && y[i + 3].horses < y[i].coconuts) {
            y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts                                                                                                       
        } else if (Math.min(y[i].lentils, y[i + 1].lentils, y[i + 2].lentils) > y[i].coconuts                                              
            && y[i + 3].apples > y[i].coconuts && y[i + 3].onions < y[i].coconuts && y[i + 3].horses < y[i + 3].maple) {                    
            y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts
        }
    } else if (y[i].trees === 4) {

        if (y[i].lentils > y[i].coconuts                                                                                                  
            && y[i + 1].apples > y[i].coconuts && y[i + 1].onions < y[i].coconuts && y[i + 1].horses < y[i + 1].maple
            && Math.max(y[i + 2].horses, y[i + 3].horses, y[i + 4].horses) < y[i].coconuts) {
            y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts
        } else if (Math.min(y[i].lentils, y[i + 1].lentils) > y[i].coconuts
            && y[i + 2].apples > y[i].coconuts && y[i + 2].onions < y[i].coconuts && y[i + 2].horses < y[i + 2].maple
            && Math.max(y[i + 3].horses, y[i + 4].horses) < y[i].coconuts) {
            y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts
        } else if (Math.min(y[i].lentils, y[i + 1].lentils, y[i + 2].lentils) > y[i].coconuts
            && y[i + 3].apples > y[i].coconuts && y[i + 3].onions < y[i].coconuts && y[i + 3].horses < y[i + 3].maple
            && y[i + 4].horses < y[i].coconuts) {
            y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts                                                                                                         
        } else if (Math.min(y[i].lentils, y[i + 1].lentils, y[i + 2].lentils, y[i + 3].lentils) > y[i].coconuts                           
            && y[i + 4].apples > y[i].coconuts && y[i + 4].onions < y[i].coconuts && y[i + 4].horses < y[i + 4].maple) {           
            y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts
        }
    } else if (y[i].trees === 5) {

        if (y[i].lentils > y[i].coconuts                                                                                                  
            && y[i + 1].apples > y[i].coconuts && y[i + 1].onions < y[i].coconuts && y[i + 1].horses < y[i + 1].maple
            && Math.max(y[i + 2].horses, y[i + 3].horses, [i + 4].horses, y[i + 5].horses) < y[i].coconuts) {
            y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts
        } else if (Math.min(y[i].lentils, y[i + 1].lentils) > y[i].coconuts
            && y[i + 2].apples > y[i].coconuts && y[i + 2].onions < y[i].coconuts && y[i + 2].horses < y[i + 2].maple
            && Math.max(y[i + 3].horses, y[i + 4].horses, y[i + 5].horses) < y[i].coconuts) {
            y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts
        } else if (Math.min(y[i].lentils, y[i + 1].lentils, y[i + 2].lentils) > y[i].coconuts
            && y[i + 3].apples > y[i].coconuts && y[i + 3].onions < y[i].coconuts && y[i + 3].horses < y[i + 3].maple
            && Math.max(y[i + 4].horses, y[i + 5].horses) < y[i].coconuts) {
            y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts
        } else if (Math.min(y[i].lentils, y[i + 1].lentils, y[i + 2].lentils, y[i + 3].lentils) > y[i].coconuts
            && y[i + 4].apples > y[i].coconuts && y[i + 4].onions < y[i].coconuts && y[i + 4].horses < y[i + 4].maple
            && y[i + 4].horses < y[i].coconuts) {
            y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts                                                                                                        
        } else if (Math.min(y[i].lentils, y[i + 1].lentils, y[i + 2].lentils, y[i + 3].lentils, y[i + 4].lentils) > y[i].coconuts          
            && y[i + 5].apples > y[i].coconuts && y[i + 5].onions < y[i].coconuts && y[i + 5].horses < y[i + 5].maple) {
            y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts
        }




    }


}



}
```

Comment: *The below code works on array y from tree values of 1 to 5, but I want to extend it to check trees value of 100*, so is this working as intended or not?

Comment: Hi, it works fine yes.  But I can't write it out to trees === 100 because it would take a long time and I may introduce errors.

Comment: Hi, what problem is the code solving? It's not clear to me what the meaning is of `y[i + 1]`, `y[i + 2]`, etc…

Comment: It might also help to provide an example of `y` when it has 5 trees.

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions to improve the readability and maintenance of your code:

- Use meaningful variable names. `i` is well understood, but for all the others give them longer names that describe what they are.
- Indent your code consistently. Everything inside that second `for` loop needs another level of indentation. You'll know it's right when the braces at the end of the code look elegant.
- Use braces around the body of loops and conditionals, even when it's not required.
- Put a semicolon after each statement, even when it's not required.
- Add line comments to describe what sections of code do.

For example if `y` is a couponBook (I'm totally guessing) then start by renaming `y` to `couponBook` wherever it's declared and then after applying these suggestions the first few lines could be be:

```
const couponCount = couponBook.length;

// reset coupons
for (let i = 0; i < couponCount; i++) {
    couponBook[i].coupons = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### DRY code with functions

Oh dear your code is completely un-maintainable, a bug waiting to happen.

When ever you find yourself writing code that is the same repeated over and over, with only some minor differences, create a function and pass it the differences as arguments. It will make the code easier to read, and maintain, and save you a lot of work.

### The reduction

The following is how I took your code and reduced it by small steps. Some are only to help clarify the patterns in my head.

#### Reduce the noise

So first lets create some alias names as its a sea text to me

```
const L = "lentils";
const C = "coconuts";
const O = "onions";
const H = "horses";
const M = "maple";
const A = "apples";
```

We can then use bracket notation to locate each item

```
y[i][L] 
// is the same as
y[i].lentils
```

#### Align the logic

Now looking at the if statements you are switching between < and > a lot.

```
if (y[i].trees === 1 ) {
    if (y[i].lentils > y[i].coconuts  && 
        y[i + 1].apples > y[i].coconuts && 
        y[i + 1].onions < y[i].coconuts && 
        y[i+1].horses < y[i+1].maple) {
            y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts
    }
} else //... and so on
```

In this case to help design better source code use only > and swap the references if there is a <. Thus the above becomes

```
if (y[i].trees === 1 ) {
    if (y[i].lentils > y[i].coconuts  && 
        y[i+1].apples > y[i].coconuts && 
        y[i].coconuts > y[i+1].onions && 
        y[i+1].maple > y[i+1].horses ) {
            y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts;
    }
} else //... and so on
```

#### Start from the smallest logic unit

and work up.

This is how to start building the functions that will help reduce overall source code size. First a function called `greater` that will do a single left side greater that right side

```
const greater = (name1, name2, i1 = 0, i2 = 0) => y[i + i1][name1] > y[i +i2][name2];
```

How we apply that function in a statement

```
if (y[i].lentils > y[i].coconuts  && 
    y[i+1].apples > y[i].coconuts && 
    y[i].coconuts > y[i+1].onions && 
    y[i+1].maple > y[i+1].horses )

// becomes      
if (
    greater(L,C) && 
    greater(A, C, 1) && 
    greater(C, O, 0, 1) && 
    greater(M, H, 1, 1) ) {
```

#### Special cases to separate functions

A function to handle min lentils via a loop so you need not have to do `y[i] ... y[i + 1]` and so on. Also the min is not really needed, rather if min lentils greater than coconuts.

```
const minLentils = (count, min = Infinity) => {
    while (count--) { Math.min(y[i + count].lentils, min) }
    return min > y[i].coconuts;
}

// Thus 
Math.min(y[i].lentils, y[i + 1].lentils, y[i + 2].lentils) >  y[i].coconuts;

// becomes 
minLentils(3);
```

And same for `maxHorses` but include start offset

```
const maxHorses = (count, offset, max = -Infinity) => {
    if (count > 1) {
        while (count--) { Math.max(y[i + offset + count].horses, max) }
        return max < y[i].coconuts;
    }
    return true; 
}

// thus 
Math.max(y[i + 2].horses, y[i + 3].horses, y[i + 4].horses) < y[i].coconuts

// becomes
maxHorses(3, 2);
```

#### What action to perform

If any of the statements are true, assign coconuts to coupons within the if statements. For now create a flag (semaphore) that if true will, on the last line inside the loop, move coconuts to coupons

```
let getCoupons = false;

 ... if statements ...

if (getCoupons) { y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts }
```

#### Find a pattern

We need to find a pattern to the logic so we can further reduce to functions

For a more complex statement, align the greater side to the left

```
if( Math.min(y[i].lentils, y[i + 1].lentils, y[i + 2].lentils) > y[i].coconuts && 
   y[i + 3].apples > y[i].coconuts && 
   y[i].coconuts > y[i + 3].onions  && 
   y[i + 3].maple > y[i + 3].horses  && 
   Math.max(y[i + 4].horses, y[i + 5].horses) < y[i].coconuts) {   

// replace Math.min and Math.max functions with the new min max functions
// and add the greater function for the rest


if( minLentils(3) && 
   greater(A, C, 3) && 
   greater(C, O, 0, 3) && 
   greater(M, H, 3, 3) && 
   maxHorses(2, 4) {
```

Still not seeing the pattern but almost there.

#### Look for similarities

Calling the function `greater(L, C)` is the same as calling `minLentils(1)` and `greater(H, C, 3)` is the same as `maxHorses(1, 3)`

So rather than manually call each function we can create an array of arrays, each sub array contains the arguments for each call to `greater`, `minLentils`, and `maxHorses`

```
// the line
if (minLentils(3) && greater(A, C, 3) && greater(C, O, 0, 3) &&  greater(M, H, 3, 3) && maxHorses(2, 4)) {    

// has the set of arguments as an array
[[3], [A, C, 3], [C, O, 0, 3], [M, H, 3, 3], [2, 4]];
```

Create a function that takes the above array that uses the first sub array to call`minLentils`, last sub array calls `maxHorses` and the rest call `greater`

```
const pass = (...args) => {
    if (! maxHorses(...args.pop()) && minLentils(...args[0])) { return false }
    while (args.length > 1) { 
        if (! greater(...args.pop()) ) { return false }
    }
    return true;
}

// the line
if (minLentils(3) && greater(A, C, 3) && greater(C, O, 0, 3) &&  greater(M, H, 3, 3) && maxHorses(2, 4)) {    

// now becomes 
if (pass([[3], [A, C, 3], [C, O, 0, 3], [M, H, 3, 3], [2, 4]]) { getCoupons = true }
```

#### Finding the logic pattern

Now we have a shorter way of writing the statements using the arrays and functions, lets convert a set of statements into the new declarative code

```
} else if (y[i].trees === 5) {
    if (y[i].lentils > y[i].coconuts &&
        y[i + 1].apples > y[i].coconuts && 
        y[i + 1].onions < y[i].coconuts && 
        y[i + 1].horses < y[i + 1].maple &&
        Math.max(y[i + 2].horses, y[i + 3].horses, [i + 4].horses, y[i + 5].horses) < y[i].coconuts) {
        y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts
    } else if (
        Math.min(y[i].lentils, y[i + 1].lentils) > y[i].coconuts &&
        y[i + 2].apples > y[i].coconuts && 
        y[i + 2].onions < y[i].coconuts && 
        y[i + 2].horses < y[i + 2].maple &&
        Math.max(y[i + 3].horses, y[i + 4].horses, y[i + 5].horses) < y[i].coconuts) {
        y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts
    } else if (
        Math.min(y[i].lentils, y[i + 1].lentils, y[i + 2].lentils) > y[i].coconuts && 
        y[i + 3].apples > y[i].coconuts && 
        y[i + 3].onions < y[i].coconuts && 
        y[i + 3].horses < y[i + 3].maple && 
        Math.max(y[i + 4].horses, y[i + 5].horses) < y[i].coconuts) {
        y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts
    } else if (
        Math.min(y[i].lentils, y[i + 1].lentils, y[i + 2].lentils, y[i + 3].lentils) > y[i].coconuts &&
        y[i + 4].apples > y[i].coconuts && 
        y[i + 4].onions < y[i].coconuts && 
        y[i + 4].horses < y[i + 4].maple && 
        y[i + 4].horses < y[i].coconuts) {
        y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts                                                                                                        
    } else if (Math.min(y[i].lentils, y[i + 1].lentils, y[i + 2].lentils, y[i + 3].lentils, y[i + 4].lentils) > y[i].coconuts && 
        y[i + 5].apples > y[i].coconuts && 
        y[i + 5].onions < y[i].coconuts && 
        y[i + 5].horses < y[i + 5].maple) {
        y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts
    }
```

becomes

```
    if(pass([[1], [A, C, 1], [C, O, 0, 1], [M, H, 1, 1], [4, 2]]) ||
        pass([[2], [A, C, 2], [C, O, 0, 2], [M, H, 2, 2], [3, 3]]) ||
        pass([[3], [A, C, 3], [C, O, 0, 3], [M, H, 3, 3], [2, 4]]) || 
        pass([[4], [A, C, 4], [C, O, 0, 4], [M, H, 4, 4], [1, 4]]) ||
        pass([[5], [A, C, 5], [C, O, 0, 5], [M, H, 5, 5], [0]]) ) { getCoupons = true }
```

We finally can see the pattern (That's me, you likely know the pattern very well)

#### Implement the common pattern

A loop can be used to create the arrays to test. That loop uses the value in y[i].trees as the count. If a function pass return true then we are done and can assign coconuts coupons

```
const testTree = (count) => {
    var j = 0;
    while(i < count) {
        if (pass([[j], [A, C, j], [C, O, 0, j], [M, H, j, j], [count - 1 - j, j + 1]])) {
            y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

### The DRY result

Gather all the functions. Wrap them in closure, add some extra args to the function `testTree` to the to allow the functions to see the index `i`, and the array `y`

Remove the aliases and use the names as strings.

The following snippet is a full replacement of your code and able to handle any value of `y[i].tree` if the pattern found continues.

```
const testTree = (()=> {
    var y, idx;
    const greater = (name1, name2, i1 = 0, i2 = 0) => y[idx + i1][name1] > y[idx +i2][name2];
    const minLentils = (count, min = Infinity) => {
        while (count--) { Math.min(y[idx + count].lentils, min) }
        return min > y[idx].coconuts;
    }
    const maxHorses = (count, offset, max = -Infinity) => {
        if (count > 1) {
            while (count--) { Math.max(y[idx + offset + count].horses, max) }
            return max < y[idx].coconuts;
        }
        return true;
    }
    const pass = (...args) => {
        if (! maxHorses(...args.pop()) && minLentils(...args[0])) { return false }
        while (args.length > 1) { 
            if (! greater(...args.pop()) ) { return false }
        }
        return true;
    }    
    return (yy, i) => {
        var j = 0; 
        const count = yy[i].tree;
        y = yy; 
        idx = i;
        while (j < count) {
            if (pass(...[
                [j], ["apples", "coconuts", j], ["coconuts", "onions", 0, j], ["maple", "horses", j, j], 
                [count - 1 - j, j + 1]
            ])) {
                y[i].coupons = y[i].coconuts;
                break;
            }
        }
    };
})();

for (const item of y) { item.coupon = 0 }
for (let i = 49; i < y.length - 1; i++) {
    const trees = y[i].trees;
    if (trees > 0 && y[i].coconuts > 0 && (i + trees) < y.length - 1) { testTree(y, i) }
}
```

### NOTE

- As there was no data to test on the is likely many typos in the code. It is aas an example only
- There where some odd values in your example that I assumed where typos on your part. If they were not typos or the pattern I found not the pattern at higher counts you will have to continue the process of reduction via functions.